# Passing a list to a function in order to move objects in tkinter (python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a rubiks slide game. The first functioning button I am doing is the clockwise button (every other button does nothing). i have the four positions of squares set, and put them in a list called board. I then call the list to the clockwise_move function from the clockwise button, and it is supposed to move the square in whatever position stated. I cannot understand why this will no work.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# --- Functions ---

def clockwise_move(square):
    canvas.coords(square[0], 500, 2, 250, 250)
    canvas.coords(square[1], 500, 490, 249, 250)
    canvas.coords(square[2], 2, 2, 249, 249)
    canvas.coords(square[3], 2, 490, 249, 250)


# --- Setup ---

main = Tk()

main.title("Rubik's Slide")
main.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
main.geometry("700x550")

# --- Objects ---

frame = ttk.Frame(main)
button_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=500, height=700)


#squares
square1 = canvas.create_rectangle(2, 2, 249, 249, fill="red")
square2 = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 2, 250, 250, fill="white")
square3 = canvas.create_rectangle(2, 490, 249, 250, fill="blue")
square4 = canvas.create_rectangle(500, 490, 250, 250, fill="black")

board = [square1,square2,square3,square4]

#buttons
clockwise = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Clockwise", command=clockwise_move(board))
clockwise.grid(column=2, row=3)

counter_clockwise = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Counterclock")
counter_clockwise.grid(column=3, row=3)

right = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Right")
right.grid(column=2, row=1)

left = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Left")
left.grid(column=2, row=2)

up = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Up")
up.grid(column=3, row=1)

down = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Down")
down.grid(column=3, row=2)

start = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Start")
start.grid(column=2, row=4)

reset = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Reset")
reset.grid(column=3, row=4)

#frame grid
frame.grid(column=1, row=1)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=1)
button_frame.grid(column=2, row=1)

#misc settings
for child in button_frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=10, pady=20)

main.mainloop() #end of GUI
```

Answer (score 0):

In your line where you assign the command `clockwise_function` onto the button, your are asigning the result of the function. So the outcome is, that your function get called after you have started your app without clicking the button.

The prove this you can simply put a print("Call") into your definition of `clockwise_function`. Instead you can wrap the function call into a lambda expression `command=lambda:clockwise_move(board))`. So instead of passing in the result of the function you are passing in the instance of an anonymous function.

An alternative would be removing the parameter `square` and using a global variable.

Without an parameter you would simply:

```
def prototype():
    print("do something")

... command = prototype # the reference to the function
```

the button click would then act like `command()`

Btw for making things easier you also could save your positions like in a dictionary, list or Enum:

here I am using an dictionary

```
# Top Left | Top Right | Bottom Left | Bottom Right
p= {"tr":[500, 2, 250, 250],
    "br":[500, 490, 249, 250],
    "tl":[2, 2, 249, 249],
    "bl":[2, 490, 249, 250]}

def clockwise_move(square):
    canvas.coords(square[0], *p["tr"])
    canvas.coords(square[1], *p["br"])
    canvas.coords(square[2], *p["tl"])
    canvas.coords(square[3], *p["bl"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `clockwise_move()` will be executer at the creation of the button.If you want to pass arguments use `lambda` keyword:

```
ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Clockwise", command=lambda: clockwise_move(board))
```